# Passing c-style string to a template function

Tags: c++, arrays, string, templates, template-argument-deduction

I can't understand the following behavior of my program. As far as I know, template argument deduction allows only 1) array- or function-to-pointer conversions or 2) const conversions. The program below should result in a compilation error. However, if I pass two c-style strings of equal length, it compiles. What is causing this behavior?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
  
  
template <typename T>
int compare(T& x, T& y) {
  return 1;
}
  
  
int main() {
   compare("abc", "abc"); // no compilation error
}
```

Comment: You are passing two arguments of type `const char[4]`. `T` is deduced to `const char[4]`, `x` and `y` are of type `const char(&)[4]`, a reference to an array of 4 const chars. That's why it only works when two string literals are of the same length - literals of different length are of different types, causing deduction to fail.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks, I didn't know I could pass c-style arrays by reference. But then the question is, given that arrays are converted to pointers, how are they also references?

Comment: `given that arrays are converted to pointers` They are converted to pointers, when parameters are pointers. The shown parameters are not pointers.

Comment: @273K Does not ```compare("abc", "abc")``` require ```compare(const char*, const char*)``` signature?`

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers in most, but not all, contexts (e.g. `sizeof("abc")` is the size of the array, not the size of the `char*` pointer). In particular, they do *not* decay to pointers when bound to a reference. No, `compare(const char*, const char*)` is not the only function signature that would make a call like `compare("abc", "abc")` valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cpp-insights to have a look](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGlvc3RyZWFtPgojaW5jbHVkZSA8dHlwZV90cmFpdHM+CiAgCiAgCnRlbXBsYXRlIDx0eXBlbmFtZSBUPgppbnQgY29tcGFyZShUJiB4LCBUJiB5KSB7CiAgcmV0dXJuIDE7Cn0KICAKICAKaW50IG1haW4oKSB7CiAgIGNvbXBhcmUoImFiYyIsICJhYmMiKTsgLy8gbm8gY29tcGlsYXRpb24gZXJyb3IKfSAgICA=&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0) at what is going on here. You will see your generated function signiture is:

```
template<>
int compare<const char[4]>(const char (&x)[4], const char (&y)[4])
{
  return 1;
}
```

This is because the type of the 2 literals are both `const char[4]` and you are taking a reference to them in your signature. The reason that it ends up being `const&` is because your type brings the `const` with it. The same way that this works:

```
template <typename T>
int foo(T& x) {
  return 1;
}

...

  int a = 5;
  const int& r_a = a;
  foo(r_a);
```